# PDI 7 o 8 error connecting to SQL Server repository

Tags: sql-server, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I have a SQL Server database repository. There are a lot of Jobs and Transformations on it.

If I use **PDI 4.4.0**, I can connect and to work on it, normally. I can create or edit any transformation or job, no problem.

But, when I tried to use **PDI 7.1 or 8** I couldn't connect to this repository.

At the application, I can create the **database connection** with no problem. The connection with the SQL Server database works fine:

[Database connection on PDI 7 or 8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCPjQ.png)

After that, when I try to configure the **repository connection** (Repository Manager > Database Repository) **in the application works fine**, with no error:

[Repository Configuration on PDI 7 or 8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRCux.png)

But at the **spoon console**, appears this message:

ERROR (version 8.0.0.0-28, build 8.0.0.0-28 from 2017-11-05 07.27.50 by buildguy) :

> This database type does not support being a repository

So, finally when I try to connect to the repository, I get this message:

[Repository Connection on PDI 7 or 8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLoCb.png)

It's strange, because I can use the same repository on PDI 4.

Is there any step that I'm missing to migrate PDI 4 to newer version?

I'm using:

- Windows 10
- PDI 4.4
- PDI 7.1
- PDI 8.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved!

It was a wrong JDBC driver version.

My database version is:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP4) - 10.0.6241.0 (X64)
```

The correct JDBC driver to connect on it, it's:

```
jtds-1.2.5.jar
```